# Haskell - store variables

Tags: haskell

I write simple interpreter and I would like to store variables. Up till now I have:

```
-- MyEnv is a map from strings into integers
type MyEnv = M.Map String Int
type TCM a = ErrorT String (StateT MyEnv IO) a
```

I have a definition

```
ms_assgn :: Assgn -> TCM()
ms_assgn (Assgn (Ident ident) exp) = do
    map <- get
    w1 <- ms_exp exp
    put (M.insert (ident w1 map))
```

and I have obtained the following mistatkes:

```
Interpret.hs:118:5:
Couldn't match type `Envnt' with `a0 -> M.Map k0 a0 -> M.Map k0 a0'
When using functional dependencies to combine
  MonadState s (StateT s m),
    arising from the dependency `m -> s'
    in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.State.Class'
  MonadState (a0 -> M.Map k0 a0 -> M.Map k0 a0) (StateT Envnt IO),
    arising from a use of `put' at Interpret.hs:118:5-7
In a stmt of a 'do' block: put (M.insert (ident w1 map))
In the expression:
  do { map <- get;
       w1 <- ms_exp exp;
       put (M.insert (ident w1 map)) }

Interpret.hs:118:20:
Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> Envnt -> k0'
            with actual type `[Char]'
The function `ident' is applied to two arguments,
but its type `String' has none
In the first argument of `M.insert', namely `(ident w1 map)'
In the first argument of `put', namely `(M.insert (ident w1 map))'
```

when I commented out the last line with put and replace it with return() it makes nothing resonable, but at least it compiles.
The ms_assgn function I understand this way:

- firstly I get my current state
- next I eveluate exp to w1
- Finanlly I would like to upadte my state

What is wrong with it? Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just an extra set of parentheses.

```
M.insert (ident w1 map) -- wrong
```

The `insert` function has type `k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a`, but those extra parentheses mean you are calling `ident` as if it were a function.

```
M.insert ident w1 map -- correct
```

However, as a semantic issue, you might run into unexpected behavior if `ms_exp exp` modifies the environment, because those changes would be lost.  I would move that above the modification of the environment:

```
ms_assgn (Assgn (Ident ident) exp) = do
  w1 <- ms_exp exp
  map <- get
  put $ M.insert ident w1 map
```

And a `get` followed by a `put` can be changed to a `modify`, currying `insert`.  Incidentally, if you ever wondered why the `Map k a` is the last argument to `insert`, this is the reason.

```
ms_assgn (Assgn (Ident ident) exp) = do
  w1 <- ms_exp exp
  modify $ M.insert ident w1
```

And if you like, you can identify that the two `do` lines are really just a single `>>=`, so...

```
ms_assgn (Assgn (Ident ident) exp) =
  ms_exp exp >>= modify . M.insert ident
```

You can see how, rather than using imperative `do`, the data flows through the monadic bind operator `>>=` into an action which modifies the environment.

Comment: +1 OMG. Thanks for fast response!! I will accept answer within few minutes. Edit: and thanks for additional explanations. I really appriciate this!